# Estilização no Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Estou com uma dúvida de iniciante.

Sempre fiz interface web na mão (**usando HTML e CSS puro, sem utilizar framework.**) eu acabei de estudar um curso que ensinava a utilizar o Bootstrap, pelo oque eu vi no curso, o bootstrap agiliza na produção de interface com seus componentes já prontos, só precisando usar suas classes no html.

Minha Dúvida é:

**1-** Utilizando o Bootstrap, ainda posso criar meu próprios arquivos css e estilizar alguns componentes ?

**2-** E se no caso possa utilizar bootstrap junto com arquivos css criados por mim, oque posso estilizar ? por que no caso o framework ajuda muito, mas não quero utilizar os componentes padrões do bootstrap, deixando as minhas páginas com uma cara só.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondendo a **1ª** questão:

Sim, você pode criar seus próprios arquivos `css`, estilizar da maneira que desejar qualquer componente que quiser.

Respondendo a **2ª** questão:

O Bootstrap te ajuda a desenvolver de maneira responsiva, sem ter que se preocupar muito com CSS p/ tudo isso acontecer, como tu mesmo citou, ele possui inúmeros componentes, que também podem ser personalizados, mas caso você não queira utilizar estes componentes não tem problema, você pode criar os teus próprios, só tem que tomar cuidado com os possíveis **conflitos** que isso pode ocasionar.

Comment: Mas geralmente quem já sabe muito sobre bootstrap, eles tentam estilizar a página com seus próprios arquivos css ? ou utilizando tudo que o bootstrap tem, sem necessidade de criar arquivos css? @Mathias

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto utilizar os componentes do bootstrap não quer dizer que a tua página não vai ficar do teu estilo, o bootstrap só tenta facilitar toda a questão da parte responsiva, óbvio ele tem estilos prontos, mas tudo pode ser manipulado, mantendo a responsividade que geralmente é o que da mais trabalho. Não quer dizer que quem tem mais experiencia ou não vai usar estilos externos, varia muito quando se trata de estilo.

Comment: Só uma dica, para complementar... caso vá fazer alterações, verifique qual propriedade não lhe agradou e crie uma outra classe que altera essa propriedade com o `! important` em vez de modificar o as classes originais do bootstrap, pois assim garante a funcionalidade padrão em outras views, quando desejar.